# Moving an object back and forth

Tags: java, loops

I am utterly stumped right now. I'm trying to make an object move back and forth by changing its x-coord(represented by z in this case) and it just won't work. I've put indicators of the value in the code and in the first instance it goes to z=284 and stays there. Here's the code:

```
public class Car
{
    BufferedImage Car= null;
    BufferedImage img = null;
    public static int z=225;
    public static int q=140;
    public static boolean c=true;
    public Car()
    {   
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("homiez.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    public void CarDraw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(img,z,q,null);
    }
    public void CarMove(double bac)
    {
        if(bac>=0.02 && bac<0.05)
        {
            if(z>=215 && z<=235 && c==true)
            {
                z++;
                System.out.println("we here");
                if(z>=235)
                {
                    c=false;
                }
            }
            else if(z>=215 && z<=235 && c==false)
            {
                z--;
                System.out.println("yo");
                if(z<=215)
                {
                    c=true;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(z);
        }

    }
}
```

This is a super important assignment and I've been stumped by it for the last hour. Can someone either point out what I'm doing wrong or provide a better alternative? Thanks so much! To clarify, this is all run again and again with a timer.

Comment: is this written in c#?

Comment: nah java. The CarMove method is what I'm having problems with.

Comment: Basically I can't figure out how to move something back and forth in a loop.

Comment: Please show us the code where the method `CarDraw` and `CarMove` is being invoked. Maybe you just forgot to repaint..